# Set form error from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My form:

```
  <form name="projectForm">
    <div>
          <md-checkbox ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items"
             ng-model="item.selected"
             ng-change="$ctrl.itemsChanged()"
             aria-label="Checkbox 1" class="md-primary">
            {{item.title}}
        </md-checkbox>
    </div>
  </form>
```

My component:

```
var BuyWizardCtrl = (function () {
    function BuyWizardCtrl() {

        this.items = [
            {
                title: 'Item 1',
                selected: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Item 1',
                selected: false
            }
        ];

    }
    BuyWizardCtrl.prototype.itemsChanged = function () {
        this.selectedItems = this.items.filter((o)=>{
          return i.selected === true;
        });
        if(this.selectedItems.length === 0){
          // Set form error here
        }
    };

    return BuyWizardCtrl;
}());
```

I have form with checkboxes. At least one of the checkboxes must be checked for the form to be valid. Is it possible to set a form error from my component controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First give name and `required` property to checkbox:

```
  <form name="projectForm">
    <div>
          <md-checkbox ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items"
             ng-model="item.selected"
             ng-change="$ctrl.itemsChanged()"
             required="true"
             name="checkbox"
             aria-label="Checkbox 1" class="md-primary">
            {{item.title}}
        </md-checkbox>
    </div>
  </form>
```

In controller:

```
 $scope.projectForm.$setDirty() = true // to set form dirty

 $scope.projectForm.checkbox.$error.required = true;//I guess You need this
```